# Unload Form1 when embedded cmd process ends

Tags: vb.net, process

I have found some code which runs a cmd.exe shell interactively in a `TextBox`; later on I will replace cmd.exe with a different character based application.

Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim P As New Process
Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = "My title"
    AddHandler P.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf DisplayOutput
    P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow() = True
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    P.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    P.Start()
    P.SynchronizingObject = TextBox1
    P.BeginOutputReadLine()
    SW = P.StandardInput
    SW.WriteLine()
End Sub
Private Sub DisplayOutput(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal output As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    TextBox1.AppendText(output.Data() & vbCrLf)
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Static Line As String
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Return) Then
        SW.WriteLine(Line & vbCrLf)
        Line = ""
    Else
        Line = Line & e.KeyChar
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

When you enter the exit command, the cmd.exe process terminates.

I like my application to unload `Form1` when this occurs, but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Set `EnableRaisingEvents = true` and subscribe to the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event

Comment: A suggestion, set `P.SynchronizingObject = Me` (always use the instance of the Parent Form as the synch object, not a child Control. The underlying code won't go on a hunt for a suitable marshaller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jimi, I added the following line to he `Form1_Load` sub:

```
P.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

and added:

```
Private Sub myProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles P.Exited
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

This is working; thank you **very** much Jimi!

Answer (score 0):

Add this above `End Sub` in your `Form1_Load` Sub:

```
p.WaitForExit()
Form1.Close()
```

- Since it looks like you're calling it from `Form1` itself, you could also use `Me.Close`.
- If `Form1` is the only form and you want the whole application to close, you can use `Application.Exit()` instead.

Some references:

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_start_notepad_wait.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Hi J. Scott, As soon as I add the p.WaitForExit() statement, my Form is no longer being displayed... Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's a blocking call. You could suggest to await [Process.WaitForExitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync), in case of a .Net 5+ app.